# Database Access in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the recommended way of accessing Database in ASP.NET MVC 3 without the use of EF?

Comment: Whichever way works best for your specific use-case =)  Seriously though, this question, I think, is a bit too open ended.  Stack Overflow itself uses [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), as they thought EF was too clunky.

Comment: It would help if you could motivate why you cannot use EF.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very fond of linq-to-sql. Together with the sqlmetal.exe tool you get a nice work flow that doesn't violate the DRY principle. Update the database and then refresh the entire code layer automatically in one step.

The downside with linq-to-sql is that there isn't the same scaffolding support in MVC for linq-to-sql as for EF. That will be the same though for any data access method except EF.

Comment: I haven't been developing myself against Database for some time. Now I have an MVC website where I need to interact with Database. Mainly I have a big search form and I might get lots of data from the server. I am also thinking of paging.

Appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

Comment: Anders, is there a link to a tutorial online using Linq-to-SQL together with sqlmetal.exe ?